# LWC.createElement anyone?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I was researching for an alternative for `document.createElement()` in LWC when I stumbled upon this article from SF's GitHub page: https://github.com/salesforce/lwc/blob/master/docs/architecture/web-components.md

> In LWC, neither of those are available yet, instead, you have to use a temporary proprietary API:
>
> `LWC.createElement('bad-1'); // returns an element`

What is `LWC` in this case, where do I get access to it from? Is it something I need to import like `track/wire/api`? Or perhaps is it a like the `pubsub` library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This only applies to the LWC OSS (Open Source Software) version. In Salesforce, you won't be able to use this method. There is discussion internally about how/if you'd be able to create components dynamically in Salesforce LWC, but for now, the correct method is to create components from Aura, e.g.:

```
$A.createComponents(
  ['c:my-lwc-component',{}], 
  function(cmp,err) { 
    if(cmp) { 
      component.set('v.dynamicComponents',cmp);
    } else { 
      alert(err); 
    }
  }
);
```

You cannot (currently) dynamically create LWC components from LWC components.

Comment: Would this be any different if I need to `createElement` inside a `<div lwc:dom="manual"></div>`? Right now I can create an element using `innerHTML`(inside a dummy div) then once that gets turned into a node I can query for it and use `appendChild` to move it to another div where it's supposed to go. But this seems like an overkill. I also would like to avoid adding aura.

Comment: @Arthlete You can create normal HTML elements, just not custom elements. They won't work correctly, won't be the correct data type, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Update on 2021, you can import it from lwc

```
import { createElement } from "lwc";
```

It works at least for jest unit tests, I haven't tried using it in a component that gets deployed but I imagine it'd work

Comment: Outside of unit tests you get the error `LWC1518: Invalid LWC imported identifier "createElement"`

Comment: Create Element is only available in Tests. Cf. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/test-lightning-web-components/write-a-jest-test